# How to scope and match all categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of groups that I want to filter based on categories.

For example:
Group #1 has "Category A" and "Category B"
Group #2 has "Category B" and "Category C"

Right now if I search for "Category A", Group #1 appears. If I search for "Category B" and "Category C" both groups appear.

**How do I use a scope in Rails where if I search for "Category B" and "Category C", only Group #2 appears?**

Group Model

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :group_categories

  scope :category, -> (category) { joins(:categories).where(categories {name: category}) }
end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

GroupCategory Model

```
class GroupCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: It depends slightly on which DB you are using but basically you want to use something like `.where(categories: { id: [b, c]}).having("COUNT(categories.id) = 2")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a straight chain because `Group.category('A').category('B')` will only return groups with categories where the category name is both 'A' and 'B' and that's impossible (a name can only have one value)

You can do it in multiple steps, get the ids of each category match and do an `intersection` to get the ids common to both groups.

```
ids = Group.category('A').pluck(:id) & Group.category('B').pluck(:id) 
Group.where(id: ids)
```

To make a `Group` method that works with any number of categories, you might do...

```
def self.matching_categories(*category_array)
  ids = category_array.map{|category| Group.category(category}.pluck(:id)}.inject(:&)
  Group.where(id: ids)
end
```

Which lets you do...

```
Group.matching_categories('A', 'B')
```

Comment: I’m not sure I would recommend this as it will load the entire table into memory and thus will not scale at all.

Comment: It won't because it's doing `pluck so it's only loading the ids from the database. Pluck is a SQL method not an array method.